# jqgrid rows updated data wash out on sorting client side

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid on my ASP.NET MVC view page.In which I am doing client side updating,sorting,paging and I am doing delete operation both on client side and server side(based on some condition).

Note : My JQGrid version is : 4.6.0

My problem is when I update or delete any record and after that do paging or sorting operation my grid is showing the initial JSON data means the data that loads first time with grid.

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "Product/List",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Category'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 20, key: false, sorttype: 'int' },
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', key: true },
        { name: 'Category', index: 'Category',  key: false },
        { name: 'Action', index: 'Action', key: false, sortable: false, formatter: DisplayActionButtons, width: 20 }],
    height: 'auto',
    jsonReader: {
        //root: 'rows',
        //page: 'page',
        total: 'total',
        //records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: 'ID'
    },
    ignoreCase: true,
    sortname: 'Name',
    loadComplete: function () {                                                                                                                        
        var cnt = $("#myGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
        var emptymessageDiv = $('#dvMessage');

        if (emptymessageDiv.length == 0) {
            $("<div id='dvMessage'> <span class='clsEmptyRow'></span></div>")
                .insertBefore("#myGrid");
        }

        if (cnt == 0 && emptymessageDiv.length == 0) {
            $("#dvMessage .clsEmptyRow").text('No Record Found');
        }
    },
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false,
    pager: "#divPager",
    rowNum: 5,
    select: false,
    loadonce: true,
    sortorder: "asc"
});
```

This is the jquery by which I am updating the record  -

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, columnName, NewValue);
```

And below is jquery to delete the record : -

```
$('#myGrid').jqGrid('delRowData', rowid);
```

Below is the screen shot before deleting the records -

[image]

And below is the screen shot after deleting all the rows of grid :-

[image]

> It's clear from the screen shot grid is not updating the values/rows data after paging,sorting,updating or deleting.

Note :
Screen shot second is showing the "No Record Found." message with the initial rows once I sort the grid or do pagination on grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of `loadComplete` callback which you use have to be changed.

First of all you should create and add `"<div id='dvMessage'> <span class='clsEmptyRow'></span></div>"` **only once** instead of appending the same div on every execution of `loadComplete`. So you should move the corresponding code fragment from `loadComplete` and place it directly *after* the grid is created. Inside of `loadComplete` you need just show/hide the div:

```js
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    ...
    loadComplete: function () {
        // call $("#dvMessage").show() or $("#dvMessage").hide()
        // depend on the number of records in the grid
        $("#dvMessage")[$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "records") > 0 ?
            "hide" : "show"]();
    },
    onInitGrid: function () {
        $(this).before("<div id='dvMessage'><span class='clsEmptyRow'>No Record Found</span></div>")
    }
});
```

You can consider to use `reccount` instead of `records`. The best choice depend on your exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your suggestion. But this will manage the Empty Row Message.But my main issue is the grid data at the time of sorting or paging.
Means once I do paging or sorting the updated data not showing.

Comment: @user3848036: You are welcome! The reason of sorting/paging problem could be different. It's important that you includes test data which you  use for the filling the grid (2-3 rows of test data would be enough). I suppose that you have problem with importing the rowid. You have `name: 'Id'` column, use `jsonReader: {id: 'ID'}` and the column `'Name'` have `key: true` additionally. What data you want really use as rowid? One other possible reason could be the code of `formatter: DisplayActionButtons` which you don't posted here and which looks like `formatter: "actions"`.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? jqGrid 4.7 have bug with the usage of `key:true` in case of `repeatitems: false` format of data. As a workaround you can use `jsonReader: { id: 1 }` (where 1 is the 0-based number of column in the input data) and **remove** `key: true` property from `colModel`.

Comment: Hi Oleg,my jqgrid version is 4.6.0.

Comment: Oleg do you mean the problem with sorting or paging is due to setting Key attribute ?

Comment: @user3848036: I mean that such problems need be **debugged**. The bug in jqGrid 4.7 could be the reaseon, but if you use 4.6 version it's another problem. You accepted the answer. Is the problem is solved already? If not, you should include **2-3 row of test data which you use as input** which one can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I thing the problem is the JSON array which loaded client is not updated while I update the grid data or delete the grid data.

That's why when I do paging or sorting the current grid rows data replace with the initial grid data.

Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: @user3848036: You problem is "data wash out on sorting client side". Isn't so? The data, which have been loaded locally, should be correctly sorted if the data are correctly loaded. If the local data can't be sorted, then the format of input data in combination with `colModel` setting have a problem which could be a bug in jqGrid or a bug in your problem. So **one have to debug** the problem with **the test data which can be used to reproduce the problem**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70903/discussion-between-user3848036-and-oleg).

Comment: Do you understand that **the format of input data is extremely important to localize the problem** I asked you multiple times to include **the test data**, but you don't do this. Why?